# Uploading facebook object.html file to blogger and getting errors

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, object

URL used for debugging using Object Debugger : 
http://www.something2gain.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_29.html

This is code in my object
.html file :

```
<head>  
  <meta property="og:type"   content="firstandroidapp_k:valentine_" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://something2gain.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_29.html" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Valentine " /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 

 </head>
```

It shows error :

```
Meta Tags In Body:  You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are embedding a complete HTML document into another one, including a second `html`, `head` and `body` element, which is of course total nonsense.

Get your HTML code fixed, and try again. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://something2gain.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_29.html